# How to debug with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, iphone-sdk-3.0, certificate

I have an iPhone and necessary certificates also, but don't know how to debug an application using xCode to iPhone.

I have all these. I have Mac Mini and iPhone 3g, but I don't know how to use all these certificates. I want to debug an application - having shake handling code. That I can't debug on simulator. So I just want to print x,y & z (nslog) while I am shaking phone. This means it's only possible when I am debugging with iPhone.

Comment: Your question isn't cleared. Do you want to "debug" your code, as in apply break points and see where it is crashing? Or do you want to move your application from Xcode to your iPhone device to see it running on your iPhone?

Comment: Yes ! Mr. @erastusnjuki. I have all these. I have mac mini & iPhone 3g. The question is - I don't know how to use all these certificates?
I want to debug an application - having shake handling code. That I can't debug on simulator. So I just want to print x,y & z ( nslog ) while I am shaking phone. Means, It's only possible when I am debugging with iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to iPhone Developer connection. Go to: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/overview/index.action

Then follow on the right tab make sure you:

1. Register your phone under "Devices"
2. Register the name of your app under "APP IDs"
3. Download an app prov profile under "Provisioning" to a local folder

Install the provisioning profile on the device, through:

1. Drag and Drop to iTunes and Sync your iPhone
2. Drag and drop to XCode menu->Window ->Organizer -> Provisioning

Confirm that the provisioning profile is in the list.

Choose the Active SDK for the Debug (Tab Located just below the close,minimize buttons of window) select: Device - 3.1.2(or other SDK build you have).

Then hit Xcode Menu -> Run -> Debugger -> Build and Go (Click Console icon which is another helpful tool)

This should:

1. Install the provisioning profile on the phone. Confirm by checking(on the iPhone)  Settings -> General -> Profiles -> NameofProvisioningProfile
2. Install and Run the app.

Comment: I would upvote this a million times if i could. Saved me from ours of dispair